# mysql search inconsistent with null values

Tags: mysql, null

I am working with MySQL Community edition 5.1.  This is a strange problem.  I have a table where a certain column value is `null`.  Lets say we have

`table1` is

```
| col_1 |   id  |
 null    1
```

When I do this:

`select col_1 from table1 where id = 1`

I get this ->

```
| col_1 |
 null
```

But when I do this:

`select col_1 from table1 where id = 1 and col_1 != "x";`

The query does not return any results.

I am expecting the second query here to return the same as the first query, since the value of `col_1` is obviously not "x".  Why is this happening?  What can I do to the second query so that it works the way it should, ie. return the row with id = 1 and all values of `col_1` except for "x"?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, comparisons with one or more `NULL` operands result in `NULL`.  You can instead use MySQL's [`NULL`-safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), `<=>`:

```
SELECT col_1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 1 AND NOT col_1 <=> "x"
```

Answer (score 3):

See [The Behavior of NULLs in SQL](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~wlam/compsci/sqlnulls)

> A boolean comparison between two values involving a NULL returns
>   neither true nor false, but unknown in SQL's three-valued logic. [3]
>   For example, neither NULL equals NULL nor NULL not-equals NULL is
>   true. Testing whether a value is NULL requires an expression such as
>   IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

So, you could change your query to:

```
select col_1 
from table1 
where id = 1 
    and (col_1 is null or col_1 != 'x');
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing NULLs to a value using != in mysql can yield unexpected results. It's a dumb quirk of SQL (sorry I don't have a better answer) NULL to them means "not having a value" so it can't be compared. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

try:

```
select col_1 from table1 where id = 1 and (col_1 != "x" OR col_1 IS NULL);
```